# sbt version varies per project directory, on the same OS

Tags: sbt

When I run `sbt` on one project directory, it issues `Detected sbt version 0.12.1` when starting off.

Typing `about` and it repeats that version.

However, running `sbt` in a different project directory identifies its version as `0.11.3`.

This reproduces even within the same terminal session. The version just varies per project directory. Couldn't find any explicit part in the build.sbt file that would cause this.

What could explain this?

In my case I'd like to use sbt 0.12.1 in both cases, how can I force that version being used also for the later project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is a SBT multi-project and since each subproject is a separate project you can use  `project/build.properties` to set different versions of SBT. The command is simply project-specific.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow
$ mkdir sbt-sample-project

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow
$ cd sbt-sample-project

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project
$ tree
.

0 directories, 0 files

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project
$ sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to sbt-sample-project (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project/}sbt-sample-project 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.2
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.2

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project
$ mkdir project

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project
$ echo "sbt.version=0.13.1-RC5" > project/build.properties

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project
$ sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project/project/}sbt-sample-project-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sbt-sample-project (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1-RC5
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-sample-project/}sbt-sample-project 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have that project around any more, but I guess I must have missed that config file, or, maybe one of the originals had it and the other just defaulted to the default of the installed sbt version (as much as the convolutions of sbt installation can be imagined as resulting in a consistent default).